# How to use realm in my basic reat native project

Tags: react-native

I've created a basic react-native project for example test. I want to use realm to store my data. I've installed realm in my project but I can't use realm without any problem.

Please use realm in a basic project of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following tutorial may help you.

[todo-app-with-react-native-realm](https://hellokoding.com/todo-app-with-react-native-realm/)

[Building An Image Browsing App With Realm, Imgur API, and React Native](https://medium.com/@dabit3/building-an-image-browsing-app-with-realm-io-imgur-api-and-react-native-331b00297906#.l76yq8tao)

[Tackling React Native Storage](https://medium.com/@bosung90/tackling-react-native-storage-part-1-d27b2bfa480f#.6j5vam7tu)